# Translating German/Latin in German marriage record from 1706?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, palaeography, translation, latin

Can anyone here help me decipher the salacious comments on this marriage record?

[image]

I get the main points. On April 6, 1706, my x-great grandfather's brother Christoph (of Untertürkheim, Württemberg) had to marry Anna Riedmann of Zazenhausen (walking distance - one to 1.5 hours on foot) because he got her pregnant ("gravida facta a Gassmanno" - there is also a birth record of a daughter, born May 23, 1706). I am interested mostly in completing the last sentence.

Comment: I've dropped the image into the question as links to images are prone to decay.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Thank you for doing this. I had intended to do something like that myself, but could not figure it out. Can you describe the process for next time (or point to a link); the stackexchange help was a bit too terse for me.

Comment: Look for the image icon at the top of the editor window -- it will allow you to drag and drop an image into the text.

Answer (score 2):

"Spuria, et deinceps Scortum, et gravida facta a Gassmanno, bis nolens volens ob favorem prolis isti tandem ante enixum partum nupsit"

"Illegitimate, and after fornication, and made pregnant by Gassmann, twice willingly refused supporting the child's birth, before delivery they finally married"

My take: (The bride was born) Illegitimate, and after fornication, and made pregnant by Gassmann, (he) twice willingly refused supporting the child's birth, (but) before delivery they finally married.

Answer (score 1):

I think I learned a few new Latin words in the process.

First, my reading of the sentence. "Spuria, et deinceps scortum, et gravida facta de Gassmanno, vir(?) nolens volens ob favorem prolix(?) isti(?) tandem ante enixum partum nupsit".

The first half is clear with an on-line Latin dictionary: "Illegitimate, and subsequently a prostitute, impregnated by Gassmann, ...". The rest is a bit woolly. "... he willy nilly as a favor? after long hesitation isti? married her before she gave birth."