# Reading descriptor preceding name in 18th century German church record?

Tags: 18th-century, german-language

I previously asked about this record in [Reading Latin date description in 18th century German church record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/reading-latin-date-description-in-18th-century-german-church-record)

[image]

Now I am curious about an abbreviation that repeats frequently in this recordset, namely the descriptor preceding the name Jacob Gassmann. The same word also precedes the name of the father of the bride, Johann Jacob Glöckler. Can anyone help me decipher it?

Answer (score 4):

The abbreviation is "evngl." (in full "evangelisch", English "evangelical", i.e. Lutheran), and is in reference to the groom and the bride, not their fathers. The religion(s) will be included in almost any Lutheran record, as mixed (Lutheran and Catholic) marriages did occur, without requiring conversion, and the record might even make distinctions between the various Protestant groups, such as Calvinists.

"Evangelisch" is sometimes abbreviated "ev." or "ev.A.B." (the latter is "evangelisch, Augsburgisches Bekenntnis", in contrast to ev.H.B., "evangelisch, Helvetisches Bekenntnis")

[I had worked out the abbreviation previously for another question, [Translating German/Latin in German marriage record from 1706?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13906), which also used "verstorb." (in full "verstorbenen", English "deceased") and "ehl." ("ehelicher"/"eheliche", legitimate) ]

Comment: "ehl" I had figured out, but I had been toying with something like "weiland" ("weyl.") to indicate that the person (father of the groom, etc.) was dead. It seems not to be used when the father of the groom is still alive.

Comment: I've seen "weiland" (formerly) in records, but used when residence or occupation have changed, rather than to indicate departure from life. I suppose it could be be used in that way too, but it doesn't quite match the letter forms in the other image.